# Relationship between $O(\log n)$ (bounded) treewidth and H-minor-free

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms

What is the relationship between graphs which have $O(\log n)$ treewidth and $\mathcal{H}$-minor-free graphs? Are graphs which have $O(\log n)$ treewidth $\mathcal{H}$-minor-free? I know that graphs which are $\mathcal{H}$-minor-free have treewidth $O(\sqrt{n})$ but I am concerned more with the relationship between $O(\log n)$ treewidth graphs and $\mathcal{H}$-minor-free graphs.

Comment: What is $\mathcal H$ here?

Comment: $\mathcal{H}$ is any subgraph: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97226/h-minor-free-graph

Comment: Take a clique on log n vertices, attach a long path to it, it is not h minor free but its treewidth is O(log n).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A proper minor-closed family of graphs has bounded treewidth if and only if it's forbidden minors includes a planar graph. Thus, either the family contains all planar graphs or has bounded treewidth. In the former case the treewidth can be $\Omega(\sqrt{n})$ and in the latter case the treewidth is $O(1)$.